# Download file from proxy server using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to download file using a proxy connection. My example code is:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("url_proxy_server");
        //wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("id", "pass", "domain");
        client.Proxy = wp;
        client.DownloadFile("http:mylink", "Save Path");
```

Is this a correct mode to download? How i can set port number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the other constructor (String, Int32)

`WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://contoso", 80);`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsh37cx.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the port in the proxy url

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("url_proxy_server:proxyPort");
```